# How to only edit the FontStyle of selected text in visual studio windows form design?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm scripting and designing a small timetable in visual studio, and I have added some rich text editors, like bold and italic. But I only want these checkboxes to affect the highlighted text, not the whole group box.

I have tried adding "Selected" or "Highlighted" before .Font = new Font but there are no results. I am quite a beginner in this field.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace timetable
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            else
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            }

        }

        private void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            }
            else
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            }
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }

        private void GroupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want only text that has been highlighted by the cursor to be edited by the check box.[This is why I am using a group box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWC9M.png)

I know this might be annoying, but can you show me how to implement the `foreach` statement into my code? like with my whole code?

After adding foreach like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace timetable
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                        box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                        box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                        box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have this:
`System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'`
And this highlighted in the designers code:

```
 private void GroupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you have in these group boxes to contain the font? 
you would need a RichTextBox then you could use the following to change the selected font...

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
            }

        }
```

Added:

as per comments you would need a foreach loop like this for the group...

```
foreach(Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if(ctrl is RichTextBox)
            {
                RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
            }
        }
```

leaving you with...

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                foreach(Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
            {
                RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
            }
        }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
            {
                RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
            }
        }
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                foreach(Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RichTextBox)
            {
                RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }


        }
```

Comment: I'm using a group box for rich text boxes.

Comment: Also it says that there is no such thing as `SelectionFont`

Comment: I have to use a group box otherwise I'll have to script each individual rich text box. 36 rich text boxes.

Comment: 'foreach(Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if(ctrl is RichTextBox)
                {
                    RichTextBox box = ctrl as RichTextBox;
                    box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
                }
            }'

Comment: // throw new NotImplementedException();